# Reading stream char by char

Tags: c, stream, realloc

I'm using this function to read, char by char, a text file or a stdin input

```
void readLine(FILE *stream, char **string) {
    char c;
    int counter = 0;

    do {
        c = fgetc(stream);
        string[0] = (char *) realloc (string[0], (counter+1) * sizeof(char));
        string[0][counter++] = c;
    } while(c != ENTER && !feof(stream));

    string[counter-1] = '\0';
}
```

But when I call it, my program crashed and I really don't know why, because I don't forget the 0-terminator and I'm convinced that I stored correctly the char sequence. I've verified the string length, but it appears alright.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` and friends, in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @nishant This clearly needs pointer to pointer since it's changing the caller's pointer. What's odd is the choice of `[]` access, it would normally be written `*string = realloc(...)`.

Comment: @unwind: I am sorry, I got confused, In that case, `*string` will be better way to represent it, instead of `string[0]`. Although its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in this code:

1. `fgetc()` returns `int`.
2. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` and friends, in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
3. Avoid using `sizeof (char)`, it's just a very clumsy way of writing `1`, so multiplication by it is very redundant.
4. Normally, buffers are grown more than 1 char at a time, `realloc()` can be expensive.
5. `string[0]` would be more clearly written as `*string`, since it's not an array but just a pointer to a pointer.
6. Your logic around end of file means it will store the truncated version of `EOF`, not very nice.

Comment: @nishant : #6 is consequent of #1.

Comment: Ok, got it. You mean to say `EOF` is 
stored as `char` then stored back at `string`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an error:

```
do {
    c = fgetc(stream);
    // What happens here?!? 
} while(c != ENTER && !feof(stream));
```

"What happens here" is that you add `c` to `string` before you've checked for EOF,  whoops.

This is very ungood:

```
    string[0] = (char *) realloc (string[0], (counter+1) * sizeof(char));
```

in a loop.  `realloc` is a potentially expensive call and you do it for every byte of input! It is also a silly and confusing interface to ask for a pointer parameter that has (apparently) not been allocated anything -- passing in the pointer usually indicates that is already done.  What if `string` were a static array?  Instead, allocate in chunks and return a pointer:

```
char *readLine (FILE *stream) {
// A whole 4 kB!
    int chunksz = 4096;
    int counter = 0;
    char *buffer = malloc(chunksz);
    char *test;
    int c;
    if (!buffer) return NULL;

    while (c = fgetc(stream) && c != ENTER && c != EOF) {
        buffer[counter++] = (char)c;
        if (counter == chunksz) {
            chunksz *= 2;
            test = realloc(buffer, chunksz);
        // Abort on out-of-memory.
            if (!test) {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            } else buffer = test;
        }
    }
// Now null terminate and resize.
    buffer[counter] = '\0';
    realloc(buffer, counter + 1);
    return buffer;
}
```

That is a standard "power of 2" allocation scheme (it doubles). If you really want to submit a pointer, pre-allocate it and also submit a "max length" parameter:

```
void *readLine (FILE *stream, char *buffer, int max) {
    int counter = 0;
    int c;

    while (
        c = fgetc(stream)
        && c != ENTER
        && c != EOF
        && counter < max - 1
    ) buffer[counter++] = (char)c;
// Now null terminate.
    buffer[counter] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Your second tip look better in this case.. But I don't want to use a max length parameter, because I don't know what's the size of my stream input..

Comment: And the garbage stored (\n or EOF) is replaced by 0-terminator after, but I don't know if it's nice..

Comment: I'm pretty late to the party, but when you `realloc()` buffer at the end of first example, is it to save space? Should I actually write `buffer = realloc(buffer, counter + 1);` instead because `realloc()` returns a pointer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, that trims the space to the actual used size.  It's probably not worthwhile unless `chunksz` has gotten relatively large or you are going to use this to store a lot of separate strings.

Comment: Thanks! BTW I think `while (c = fgetc(stream) && c != ENTER && c != EOF)` should be `while ((c = fgetc(stream)) && c != ENTER && c != EOF)` ?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference there, since either way the first clause evaluates to the value of `fgetc(stream)` and is assigned to `c` -- which is a bit of a flaw if `stream` isn't text.   Where it would make a difference is if we want to be more robust (allowing for null chars) and succinct: `while (c = fgetc(stream) != EOF && c != ENTER)`.  That assigns `fgetc(stream) != EOF` to `c`, meaning `c` will always be either 1 or 0.  But `while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && c != ENTER)` preserves the value of `c` and avoids the null char pitfall.  See what 6 more years of S.O. has done for me :D

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
string[counter-1] = '\0';
```

to

```
string[0][counter-1] = '\0';
```

You want to terminate string stored at `string[0]`.